# Python: Accessing defined variables from method

Tags: python, var

I have code which doesn't work, and I'm not quite sure why. Heres my code:

```
pal1= timingPage(createSelenium.sel)
pal1.gpsTimingMode.setOption()
```

meanwhile, heres timingpage class:

```
class timingPage:

    def __init__(self,sel):
        self.gpsTimingMode = option(self.selObject)
        self.gpsTimingMode.id="hi"
```

and in the option class:

```
class option:
    def setOption(self):
        print str(self.id)
```

This error gets thrown:

```
AttributeError: option instance has no attribute 'id'


class option:

def __init__(self,sel):
    self.selObject=sel
def setOption(self):
    print str(self.id)
    print "selOption called"
    # this method is a general method for selecting a option, so that the caller does not need to know the type or structure
    for pre in self.prereq:
        print "Prerequisite"+str(pre)+"called"
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `prereq`?  It's not anywhere in the code you posted.  Can show the code for the `option` class?

Comment: Are you intending to print the python object id? if so, use `print id(self)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define `object.id` anywhere you can't access it.

See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) on how to define attributes.

Comment: Even if I am calling it directly after creating an instance of option?
I have:   gpsTimingMode.id="hi"

Comment: Yeah but you don't create an attribute `object.id` so you can't write to / read from it… See the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) for details on defining attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define `self.id` anywhere, you won't be able to call it.

To get around this, consider defining it in your `__init__`.